# Can I set up linux to accept a dial up connection from my old windows95 laptop?

Tags: linux, networking, slackware, modem, ppp

I've got a really old laptop running Windows 95, and I'd like to be able to connect it to my home network. It doesn't have an ethernet jack, nor a usb port. It does have an internal dial up modem though, and I'd like to try connecting to another modern machine running slackware. This other machine also has an internal dial up modem, so it seems like it should be possible.
I'd appreciate any advice or pointers to relevant information.

Comment: You are asking for a dial-in server, a.k.a a Remote Access Server, a.k.a a Point-to-Point Protocol server. This is probably what you are trying to accomplish: http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_dialin_server

You will need a Linux compatible modem to dial-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you really want is just to connect the notebook to your network, check if it has a PC Card or PCMCIA slot. Most notebooks, even very old ones, should have that. Then you can find a second hand PCMCIA Ethernet card for almost nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is indeed a PCMCIA slot and I may end up going down this route.